# Magento 3 decimals when ordering products in backend

Tags: php, magento

When creating a product in magento catalog we have 3 decimals but when they are added to a order they become 2 and lose the 3rd number, leaving the price rounding up to a wrong number and adding a cent to the price.

For example 350.00 EUR becomes 350.01 EUR when added to cart then this shows up every where.

The VAT is 21 percent and we tried changing how VAT works (per item, per line, per cart) but it works on some producs but not all.

We atleast need to find how to make 3 decimals when creating an order on the product list, this way we could fix some of the problem.

Preview: 
Need 3 decimals in the custom price input:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP5tl.jpg

Thanks and bye!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change any database fields, magento by default supports working with prices up to 4 decimals precision, but it does by default work with a precision of 2.

In order to force magento make all calculations in cart/checkout/order with a precision of 3 you must override `Mage_Core_Model_Store::roundPrice()` like below

```
function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 3);
}
```

For displaying purposes (if you want also **visually** to see prices with 3 decimals) you must override `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::format()`  like below

```
public function format($price, $options = array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 3, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```

Also please note that the rounding issue are a well known problem by magento, even if you change the precision and your example may work fine(you wouldn't see the extra .01), other situations may break. Magento posted some [recommedations & best practices](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-ce-18-ee-113-tax-calc) on how to setup taxes to minimize this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I also had same issue.I made change in database in price field.Please check in database for field datatype. Make it decimal(10,3) or decimal. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Could you tell me where I should look in the database? Thanks!

Comment: I had issue in my custom table. But you can look in product tables like catalog_product_entity_decimal or catalog_product_entity_int.